# Deleting a Row in a rowReorder Table Resets Reordering

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

Here's a jsfiddle to show what I'm talking about:

https://jsfiddle.net/ChakronSA/sdwfcrmr/

You can click and drag on either the "Order" or "Name" columns. To recreate this issue:
1. Drag "Name 4" to the top so it's above "Name 1"
2. Click the Delete button next to "Name 2"

When deleting "Name 2", "Name 4" returns to its original position. How can I make it stay put? I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks.

Specifically curious about why this isn't doing what I expect:

```
$(document).on("click", ".myTableDeleteRow", function() {
  table
    .row($(this).parents('tr'))
    .remove()
    .rows().every(function(rowidx) {
    var data = this.data();
    data[0] = rowidx + 1;
    this.data(data);
    })
    .draw(false);
});
```

Comment: I never used dataTable but im assuming its because after you call `remove()` you get `rows()` and this probably refers to the initial declaration of table.  You probably need to update the table before doing this.

Comment: That was my initial thought too. After removing the rows I tried calling draw() but it didn't change anything. I think this is unfortunately specific to something that the rowReorder dataTables plugin is doing, so I've been having trouble finding the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a fix not using just tableData

```
$(document).on("click", ".myTableDeleteRow", function() {
  table
   .row($(this).parents('tr'))
   .remove()
   .draw(false);

  $.each($('#myTable tr td:first-child'),function(index,val){
    $(this).html(index+1)
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. It looks like the second draw() call was causing my problem.